# convert Javascript dot notated objects to array based style

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's what I want: To set a value dependent on a property key. The key could be flat e.g. 'name' or an object e.g. 'business.mobile' (nested). 
What's wrong: It works fine for flat keys, but not for nested properties.
Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var prop = <a property>;

var nestedKey; // e.g. for business.mobile
var value;
// nested properties
if ((prop.key).toString().indexOf('.') !== -1) {
  nestedKey = prop.key.split('.');
} else {
  // flat properties
  value = $scope.modalModel[prop.key];
}

$scope.formProperties.push({
  name: prop.key,
  value: $scope.modalModel[value || nestedKey[0]][nestedKey[1]],
});
```

Here we have a tiny conversion to the "array style".  Without this conversion the nested properties are not accepted.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?  You seem to already have code that works with one level of nested keys.

Comment: I'd like to know: Why it does not work default for nested props? And Is there a better solution, maybe a function in a library, I could use?

Comment: *The key could be flat e.g. 'name' or an object e.g. 'business.mobile' (nested).* Is key always a string (dot-separated when nested)?

Comment: The key is not always a string. Here is an real example :
 {  
         "name":"w22aAAAA",
         "uuid":"862f57ca-68bf-11e4-90d0-00093d13f361",
         "permission":{  
            "canRead":true,
            "canWrite":true,
            "canExecute":true
         },
         "layout":{  
            "configuration":"",
            "type":2
         },
         "tiles":[  
            "8aeff3af-68bf-11e4-90d0-00093d13f361",
            "3274ca98-6fd5-11e4-90d0-00093d13f361",
            "5646ab46-6f2a-11e4-90d0-00093d13f361"
         ]
      }

Comment: What parts of the example do you need to access the properties of `$scope.modalModel`? You should improve your question with that example and an example of the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Create logic for one level
- Wrap logic in JSON.parse callback
- Call JSON.stringify on the data
- Call JSON.parse on the result of JSON.stringify